# Understanding the eval function used to define combinators and expression (Lambda) in Haskell

Tags: haskell, combinatory-logic

I find the use of pattern matching for `eval (App x y)` redundant since both cases would return `App x y`. I wonder if `eval (App x y)` is needed at all because we have `eval x = x` at the end, which should also include `eval (App x y)`

```
data Expr = App Expr Expr | S | K | I | Var String | Lam String Expr deriving (Show,Eq)
eval :: Exp -> Exp
eval (App I x) = eval x 
eval (App (App K x) y) = eval x
eval (App (App (App S f) g) x) = eval (App (App f x) (App g x))
eval (App x y)
 | evalx == x  = (App evalx (eval y)) --test if x is a Lam (not other possible values of Exp)
 | otherwise = eval (App evalx y)
     where evalx = eval x
eval (Var x) = (Var x)
eval x = x
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. With your definition, e.g. `eval (App (App I I) I)` yields `I` and not `App (App I I) I` ... So how do you get the idea that the `App x y` case doesn't do anything?

Comment: This doesn't seem redundant to me since there are different cases for `App` to be matched on and thus identifying all of them and extracting the needed data for processing.

Comment: you should include your data types definition(s) and some sample expressions.

Comment: sorry you are right . `data Expr = App Expr Expr | S | K | I | Var String | Lam String Expr deriving (Show,Eq)

Comment: I didn't see that you made the edit. Only saw it now by chance. BTW on SO we can use @ to notify someone. you type @, then type first letter of their name, and SO suggests matching names; then you press tab for completion. :)

Comment: why do you have `Lam` terms at all? the whole point of SKI calculus is not to have named variables at all. are you treating them as values?